# OpenERP trunk server gives import Error psutil

Tags: python, odoo, importerror, openerp-7

I download trunk version of OpenERP from lauchpad. When i start server it's gives following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./openerp-server", line 2, in 
    import openerp
  File "/home/jack/trunk/trunk-server/openerp/**init**.py", line 72, in 
    import http
  File "/home/jack/trunk/trunk-server/openerp/http.py", line 37, in 
    from openerp.service import security, model as service_model
  File "/home/jack/trunk/trunk-server/openerp/service/**init**.py", line 28, in 
    import server
  File "/home/jack/trunk/trunk-server/openerp/service/server.py", line 10, in 
    import psutil

ImportError: No module named psutil

Comment: Before asking question here why not go for proper search and read document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting this error because psutil is not installed. you have to install psutil using this command.

`sudo apt-get install python-psutil` in terminal. after this restart server. This will solve your error.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. can you please tell me what usage of that module ?

Comment: For such type of Doubts you can use Google also. Any ways, The Python code in OpenERP does not seem to be doing weird level stuff, so it should run on any POSIX-compliant platform. So I'm tempted to say "yes" (with 90% confidence ;-) ). This does not mean that getting all the dependencies right will be a breeze, and you may need to recompile stuff manually. So better to use these python inbuilt modules.  For more details, visit this site. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

Comment: Thanks you for give me link.